# Non-Linear Programming with \min operator in the constraint

Tags: ds.algorithms, optimization, convex-optimization

Can the following non-linear program be solved in polynomial time? $c_{ij}$'s are constants and known. Each $c_{ij}$ is either -1 or 1.

\begin{align}
  \text{maximize } &\sum_{i,j=1}^{m,n} c_{ij} \gamma_{ij} \notag\\
  \text{subject to: }& \notag\\
  &  \gamma_{ij} = \min\{1, \sum_{k = 1}^{K}{x_{ik}y_{jk} }\}  && 
\forall i,j\\
  & 0 \le x_{ik}, y_{jk} \le 1 && \forall i,j,k 
\end{align}

Comment: Should $mn$ be replaced with ​ $m\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}n$ ? ​ ​ ​ (If no, then I don't know what that sum means.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Seems unlikely.  Even for $K=1$, deciding whether a given instance has  value at least $\ell$ is equivalent to the following problem: given a bipartite graph $G=(V,W,E)$, decide whether it has an induced subgraph $G'=(V',W',E')$ with at least $\ell$ more edges than non-edges (that is, $2|E'| - |V'|\,|W'| \ge \ell$).  I'd guess that is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think, there might exist a randomized algorithm/FPT to solve this optimization problem.